# Using redux data in JS object

Tags: reactjs, redux, highcharts

What I'm trying to do here is to get the data from redux store and use it in Options object. I can't figure out how to populate parts of Options obj with data from redux. In redux-logger I see that everything is ok and data is being stored at redux state. I think the problem might be with accessing props in Options object, but have no clue how to pass those. Highcharts is used for data display.

Does this.props.myValue to access data from mapStateToProps works only inside of react component which is connected to redux store?

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'

import PreviewNav from '../../../components/preview-nav/preview-nav.component'

import './price-history.styles.scss'

const Options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Price History'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Date of change'
        },
        categories: [...this.props.time]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Price in $'
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Price',
            data: [...this.props.price]
        }
    ]
}

const PriceHistory = ({ match }) => {
    console.log(this.props.time)
    return (
        <div>
            <PreviewNav id={match.params.id} />
            <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={Options} />
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        price: state.itms.quantityChanges.value,
        time: state.itms.quantityChanges.time
    }
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(Options)
export default PriceHistory
```

Comment: Yes, you must wrap the PriceHistory component with the connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes you access props only inside component.
try to do it like this

```
const setOptions (props) = {
const Options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Price History'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Date of change'
        },
        categories: [...props.time]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Price in $'
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Price',
            data: [...props.price]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change last two lines to,

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PriceHistory);
```

To connect component we have to pass our component as the function parameter to the **connect** api.